# SQL select rows from table A which have no rows in table B

Tags: sql

```
table A      table B
----------   ---------
id name      a_id
1  Chris     1
2  Steve
3  Allen
```

What would be the proper sql query to select all the rows in A which id's don't occur in table B.

```
Returns: 2 Steve, 3 Allen
```

Answer (score 1):

There's the proper way and there's the easy-to-understand way. Any halfway decent sql engine will turn them both into the same thing on the back end, so I always write this one the easy way:

`select * from A where id not in (select a_id from B)`

Comment: This principle doesn't work so well when you manage federated databases.

Comment: @Johann Blais what do you mean?

Comment: It is off-topic since you have only one database. In a federated database, two tables can come from different child databases, bringing a new set of optimization issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
  A.id,  
  A.Name  
from A   
  left join B on A.id = B.A_id  
where 
  B.A_id is null
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM TableA
  EXCEPT
  SELECT a_id
  FROM TableB
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.*
  FROM A
  LEFT JOIN B ON B.A_id = A.id
 WHERE B.a_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

And as there are many ways that lead to Rome, or StackOverflow, here's an alternative:

```
SELECT * FROM [A] AS [tblA] 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [B] AS [tblB] WHERE [tblB].[A_id] = [tblA].[id])
```